# Autofocus input on modal show

Tags: jquery, materialize

I'm trying to focus an input when a user clicks a button to open a modal. I'm using MaterializeCSS and can't seem to get this to work with multiple attempts. This is the code they're running to open a modal:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.modal').modal();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal({
        onOpenEnd: function() {
            $('your-input-selector').focus();

            // or autofocus first one
            // $(this).find('input').eq(0).focus();
        }
    });
});
```